# Spark Dynamic Partition overwrite on multiple columns are producing blank output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 2.3.0 on HDP 2.6.5 cluster with hadoop 2.7.5. I came across a an issue from this evening. I am using the below dynamic partition overwrite in one of my validation script.

```
DF.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("run_date","dataset_name").mode("overwrite").csv("/target/path")
```

But it is only writing blank output with _SUCCESS file. I have the below configuration set in my spark session.

```
.config("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
```

This will work fine if I remove any one of the columns from .partitionBy()

I am wondering why its not writing dataframe output to csv  with dynamic partition on multiple columns!

It will be great if any one can help me out on this.

Comment: overwrite of existing partition u mean?

Comment: @thebluephantom Nope. Even if I am creating a a fresh new partition , it's writing blank output. with Single column  in partitionBy() clause , dynamic partition overwrite is working as expected. But with multiple partition columns as above it's giving only _SUCCESS file. With static partition overwrite it's working as expected for multiple columns. Also in HDP 3.1 cluster , this scenario of multiple column dynamic partition overwrite is working fine with spark 2.3.2. Issue seems to be in HDP 2.6.5 only

Comment: sounds like a bug

Comment: Yeah. Even I am suspecting the same. Luckily , we have already migrated to HDP 3.1 officially. So issue is resolved as of now 

Comment: Then you should answer and state it is a bug.

Comment: Added my answer as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be a bug with HDP 2.6.5 since the same scenario of dynamic partition overwrite with multiple columns worked perfectly with HDP 3.1 and spark 2.3.2.